# Matrix Inequality involving bilinear forms

Tags: matrices, inequality, optimization, geometric-inequalities

For an $m \times n$ matrix  $(a_{ij})$ of real numbers, we want to show that the following two conditions are equivalent:

1) $|\sum_{ij} a_{ij} x_i y_j | \leq 1$ for $x_i, y_j \in \{\pm 1\}$

2) $|\sum_{ij} a_{ij} x_i y_j| \leq \max |x_i| \max |y_j|$ for all numbers $x_i$, $y_j$.

Clearly, 2 implies 1. I would like to know why the reverse is true.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x, y) \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R ^m $, we define $$u_j = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 1~& \text{if $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x_i \ge 0$}\\ -1& \text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$ Now $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i\right| = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_iu_j$$ Now we define $$v_i = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 1~& \text{if $\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}u_j \ge 0$}\\ -1& \text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$ so we have $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} u_j\right| = \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} v_iu_j$$ Now $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x_iy_j\right| \le \sum_{j=1}^m \left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i\right||y_j| = \max |y_j| \left(\sum_{j=1}^m \left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i\right|\right) = \max |y_j| \left(\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_iu_j\right) \le \max |y_j| \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left|\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} u_j\right||x_i|\right) \le \max |y_j| \max |x_i| \sum_{i=1}^n \left|\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} u_j\right| = \max |y_j| \max |x_i| \sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}v_iu_j$$

Then assume that 1) holds so 2) holds also.

Comment: Great answer, Youem!  Can I aska follow up?  If I know the matrix satisfies the above conditions and is symmetric, is it true that $|\sum_{ij} a_{ij} x_i x_j| \leq 2$ for all $x_i \in \{\pm 1\}$?

Comment: Yes you can ask what do you want

Comment: Thanks, I think I should be able to use the polarization identity: $\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle Au, u\rangle - \langle A v, v\rangle$ where $u = (x+y)/2$ and $v = (x-y)/2$.

Comment: However, this enlarges the set to include $\{\pm 1, 0\}$ vectors.

Comment: Do you want to prove that $|\sum_{ij} a_{ij} x_i x_j| \leq 2$ ? for $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$

Comment: Sorry, no I'd like to show that if for all $x \in \{\pm 1\}^n$, $|\sum a_{ij} x_i x_j| \leq 1$ then $|\sum a_{ij} x_i y_j| \leq C$ for all $x_i. y_j \in \{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: I believe that $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, the first $x_i$ are in $\{\pm 1\}$ also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76081/discussion-between-youem-and-jkv).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose 2) holds. Then $x,y$ (or possibly $-x,y$) solve
$\max \{ y^T Ax | x \in [-1,1]^n, y \in [-1,1]^m \}$.

It is straightforward to show that we can always choose $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$, $y \in \{-1,1\}^m$.

Suppose $y_k \in (-1,1)$ then for sufficiently small $t$ we have
$(y+t e_k)^T Ax \ge y^TAx$ and $y_k +t e_k \in \{-1,1\}$. Similarly for $x$.

Hence there is always a maximising $x,y$ such that $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$, $y \in \{-1,1\}^m$.

It follows that we need only consider $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$, $y \in \{-1,1\}^m$, from which it follows that 1) implies 2).

Actually, the above is too complicated.

We have $[-1,1]^p = \operatorname{co} E_p$, where $E_p= \{ \pm e_1 \pm \cdots \pm e_p \}$ and that $\max_{x \in [0,1]^p} a^T x = \max_{x \in E_p} a^T x$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\max_{x \in [0,1]^n, y \in [0,1]^m} y^TAx &=& \max_{x \in [0,1]^n} \max_{ y \in [0,1]^m} y^TAx \\&=& \max_{x \in [0,1]^n} \max_{ y\in E_m} y^TAx \\&=&  \max_{ y\in E_m} \max_{x \in [0,1]^n} y^TAx \\&=&  \max_{ y\in E_m} \max_{x \in E_n} y^TAx \\&=&  \max_{x \in E_n, y\in E_m} y^TAx
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^m{\times\,}\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_i,y_j\in \{-1,1\},\;\text{for all}\;i,j\}$.

Let $D = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^m{\times\,}\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_i,y_j\in [-1,1],\;\text{for all}\;i,j\}$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m{\times\,}\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$f(x,y)=\sum a_{ij}x_iy_j$$
for $1\le i \le m,\;1\le j \le n$.

Assume $|f(x,y)|\le 1$, for all $(x,y)\in S$.

For each each coordinate $v\in \{x_i\}\cup \{y_j\}$, regarding $v$ as unknown, with the other coordinates held fixed, $f$ is a linear polynomial in $v$. It follows that the maximum and minimum values of $f$ on $D$ can be realized at points of $S$.

Hence, $|f(x,y)|\le 1$, for all $(x,y)\in D$.

The desired result 
$$|f(x,y)|\le \max |x_i| \max |y_j|$$
for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^m{\times\,}\mathbb{R}^n$
follows by an appropriate scaling of $x$ and $y$.

Explicitly . . .

Let $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^m{\times\,}\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $X=\max(|x_i|)$, and let $Y=\max(|y_j|)$.

We want to show $|f(x,y)|\le XY$.

If $X=0$ or $Y=0$, then $x=0$ or $y=0$, so $f(x,y)=0=XY$.

Next, assume $X,Y > 0$.

Then $\bigl({\large{\frac{x}{X}}},{\large{\frac{y}{Y}}}\bigr)\in D$, hence
$$
|f(x,y)|
=
XY
\left|f
\bigl(
{\small{\frac{x}{X}}},{\small{\frac{y}{Y}}}
\bigr)\right|
\le (XY)(1) 
=XY
$$